# CSS transform not working in Android

Tags: android, css

What I am trying to do is fix a caption over an image, using the following approach.
For some reason either transform or translate with percentage is not working on my Android devices.

It works fine on my desktop browser though.
How can I fix this?

`CSS`

```
.city-caption h2 
{
     font-weight: 800;
     color: white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing "-" before `webkit-transform`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the correct sintax is :

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Note the "-" before "webkit-transform"

Hope it helps